# Angular How to make basic FormControl work in Storybook

Tags: angular, storybook

I have a very basic component that uses FormControl, it works well when running "ng s -o", but in the storybook, it doesn't work(there is an error).

The task component looks like this(right now its only a name, it's not really a task)

```js
import { Component,  } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-task',
  templateUrl: './task.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./task.component.css']
})
export class TaskComponent   {
  name = new FormControl('my text');
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <input type="text" [formControl]="name" />
    <p>Value: {{ name.value }}</p>
</div>
```

The story:

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Meta, Story, moduleMetadata } from '@storybook/angular';

import { TaskComponent } from './task.component';

export default {
  title: 'MyTask',
  component: TaskComponent,
  decorators: [
    moduleMetadata({
      imports: [CommonModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
      declarations: [TaskComponent],
      providers: [],
    }),
  ],
} as Meta;


const Template: Story = (args) => ({
  props: args,
});

export const BasicTask = Template.bind({});
```

The result in "ng s -o":

[image]

But in story book I have error in devtools:

```
ERROR TypeError: control.registerOnChange is not a function
    at setUpModelChangePipeline (forms.mjs:3160:1)
    at setUpControl (forms.mjs:2990:1)
    at FormControlDirective.ngOnChanges (forms.mjs:4625:1)
    at FormControlDirective.rememberChangeHistoryAndInvokeOnChangesHook (core.mjs:1523:1)
    at callHook (core.mjs:2505:1)
    at callHooks (core.mjs:2464:1)
    at executeCheckHooks (core.mjs:2396:1)
    at selectIndexInternal (core.mjs:9830:1)
    at ɵɵadvance (core.mjs:9819:1)
    at TaskComponent_Template (template.html:3:8)
```

Any suggestions on what to do?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: please provide stackblitz with issue

Comment: @Exception I didn't find a way to show Storybook inside a stackblitz. Stackblitz will only show my component...or am I wrong?

Comment: what is storybook here

Comment: In the snippets above, is where I do: export const BasicTask = Template.bind({}); (all this file)
And storybook in general is: https://storybook.js.org/

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use a form group additional to only the form control?

Something like that:

Component:

```
Component({
  selector: 'app-task',
  templateUrl: './task.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./task.component.css']
})
export class TaskComponent   {
  group = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl('my text')
  });
}
```

Template:

```
<form [formGroup]="group">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <input type="text" formControlName="name" />
    <p>Value: {{ name.value }}</p>
  </div>
</form>
```